# Laravel 5 How to submit dates to SQL database

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've been stuck for days, I can't get my dates to save to my database and having issue after issue. Can someone recommend a video/article or just plain explain on how to fully deal with dates?

Migration

```
    $table->dateTime('start_date');
    $table->dateTime('end_date');
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $this->validate(request(), [

    'name' => 'required',
    'description' => 'required',
    'status' => 'required',
    'startdate' => 'required',
    'enddate' => 'required'

  ]);

 Event::create(request(['name', 'description', 'status', 'start_date', 'end_date']));

    return redirect('/events');
}
```

Model

```
THIS IS OBVIOUSLY THE ISSUE and I would paste things but theres multiple things I've put here and nothing works.
```

This is the dd of the request

```
 +request: ParameterBag {#40 ▼
#parameters: array:6 [▼
  "_token" => "yjU5A0Z5dpRES7KWK82fRMbHMRQkaooe27vYKlo7"
  "name" => "My first event"
  "status" => "Inquery"
  "description" => "this is my desc"
  "start_date" => "02/16/2017 6:36 PM"
  "end_date" => "02/24/2017 6:37 PM"
]
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: The database connection in the .env file is mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the dates to the database (via laravel) in a format that it understands.

You're using the `d/m/Y H:i A` format on the front end (see the [PHP Date page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more on date formats). The database likes to receive dates in the format `Y-m-d H:i:s`. Even better, laravel can insert Carbon date objects into the database with no formatting on your part.

As Carbon comes with Laravel, you can use it to change your date string into a Carbon object.

```
$start_date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i A', $request->input('start_date'));
```

As you can see, Carbon takes the date string and as the format has been supplied, it's easy for it to create a new Carbon object. This can be directly inserted into the database.

If you really wanted, you could explicitly cast it into a string with `$start_date->toDateTimeFormat();`, or even `$start_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`.

```
// put the first three elements in the insertData array
$insertData = request()->only(['name', 'description', 'status']);
$insertData['start_date'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i A', $request->input('start_date'));
$insertData['end_date'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i A', $request->input('end_date'));

// both dates are now carbon objects, not strings 
Event::create($insertData);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, im confused about what you said at the end about using an event to insert the model. the model is named Event thats why its in my controller.

Comment: Gotcha. I thought it was code to create an Event in laravel. I'll remove that part.

Comment: so where would i place your line of code? I'm pretty new to laravel and i went through the videos but still learning :) appreciate the help :)

Comment: Does this go in my model or controller?

Comment: It looks ok to me as it is, i.e. in the controller

Comment: My controller store method is below and I'm getting error my controller below, 

SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '02/16/2017 1:40 PM' for column 'start_date' at row 1

Comment: public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $this->validate(request(), [

        OTHER FIELDS OMITTED FOR COMMENT LENGTH

        'start_date' => 'required',
        'end_date' => 'required'

      ]);

      $start_date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i A', $request->input('start_date'));
      $end_date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i A', $request->input('end_date'));

        Event::create(request(['name', 'description', 'status','start_date', 'end_date']));

        return redirect('/events');
    }

Comment: How are you making the insert? You'll need to pass in the carbon dates, not the original request dates

Comment: Thanks for that tip, i used that info and removed  Event::create from my controller and set it up the longer way (as per docs) with more code. The  Event::create way was a shorter form that I learned about in Laracasts.

Comment: `Event::create()` should still work fine. In the code you give above you're passing in the original request, so the dates would still be in the wrong format. I've updated the code to show how.